# Sequence of conditional expectations - convergence

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $\{X_n\}$ and $\{Y_n\}$ be sequences of random variables s.t. $Y_n\ge 0$ a.s. and
$$
\mathsf{E}[\lvert X_n-Y_n\rvert\mid \mathcal{G}_n]\to 0 \quad\text{a.s.},
$$
where $\{\mathcal{G}_n\}$ is a sequences of sub-$\sigma$-fields (not necessarily nested). Can we show that
$$
\mathsf{E}[\lvert X_n\vee 0-Y_n\rvert\mid \mathcal{G}_n]\to 0 \quad\text{a.s.}?
$$

---

In the unconditional case ($\mathcal{G}_n=\{\emptyset,\Omega\}$) it follows from the DCT (assuming that the dominating r.v. exists), i.e.
$$
\mathsf{E}\lvert X_n\vee 0 - Y_n\rvert\le o(1)+\mathsf{E}\lvert X_n\vee 0-X_n\rvert\to 0.
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $|X_n \lor 0 - Y_n| \le |X_n - Y_n|$ almost surely, you have $E[|X_n \lor 0 - Y_n | \mid  \mathcal{G}_n] \le E[|X_n  - Y_n | \mid  \mathcal{G}_n]$ for each $n$.

Comment: Haha. I oversimplified the original problem. So it became ridiculously simple...